# How do I use filter_input to get parameter array?

Tags: php

Well I have this page

```
domain.com/bla.php?p[]=1&p[]=2&p[]=3&p[]=4
```

Now, `$_GET['p']` works as expected. It's an array

However, `filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p')` produces `false`.

Now how do I get the array value of `p` using `filter_input`

Answer (score 6):

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) say, you should use the `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` flag:

```
filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it always going to be be an array? If so, filter_input_array could work for you: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php

Something like this should do the trick (untested):

$data   = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'p', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use:

```
print_r( filter_input_array ( INPUT_GET ));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php